# Running tests on different test environments using Spock

Tags: testing, spock, test-environments

I am presently writing REST API tests using REST Client and Spock. I want to be able to run my tests on the different test environments. My test data varies between test environment, so need to use and specify different input data per environment. For a sample test below

```java
class MathSpec extends Specification {
    def "maximum of two numbers"() {
        expect:
            Math.max(a, b) == c

       where:
            a | b || c
            1 | 3 || 3
    }
}
```

Am I able to specify different data tables for each environment?

```java
class MathSpec extends Specification {
    def "maximum of two numbers"() {
         expect:
              Math.max(a, b) == c

         where:
              @TEST 
              a | b || c
              1 | 3 || 3

              @PROD
              a | b || c
              4 | 5 || 6

     }
 }
```

If not, what's the best way to approach this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to my mind to achieve your expectation is to prepare the data before running test methods based on some condition (e.g. execution environment) and then use this predefined data in your tests. Consider following example:

```java
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class EnvBasedDataSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    static Map data = [:]

    def setupSpec() {
        /* If you want to pick variable from env variables, use:
         * System.getenv().getOrDefault('execution.environment', 'test')
         *
         * If you want to provide variable like -Dexecution.environment=test, use:
         * System.getProperty('execution.environment', 'test')
         */
        def executionEnvironment = System.getProperty('execution.environment', 'test')

        switch (executionEnvironment) {
            case 'test':
                data = [a: 1, b: 3, c: 3]
                break
            case 'prod':
                data = [a: 2, b: 4, c: 4]
                break
        }
    }

    @Unroll
    def "maximum of two numbers (#a, #b) == #c"() {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        a       | b         || c
        data.a  | data.b    || data.c
    }
}
```

In this example we prepare shared `data` that holds values we will use in tests. Here we are expecting that the execution environment information will be passed as

```
-Dexecution.environment=value
```

property (alternatively you can pass the same information using env variables). In this example we also use the default value if given property is missing - `test` in this case (it will prevent test from failing if you forgot specifying your execution environment variable).

### Alternative: `@IgnoreIf` conditional exection

Spock supports conditional execution. Take a look what the same test would look like if we use `@IgnoreIf` approach:

```java
import spock.lang.IgnoreIf
import spock.lang.Specification

class AlternativeEnvBasedDataSpec extends Specification {

    @IgnoreIf({ System.getProperty('execution.environment') == 'prod' })
    def "maximum of two numbers (test)"() {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        a  | b  || c
        1  | 3  || 3
    }

    @IgnoreIf({ System.getProperty('execution.environment') == 'test' })
    def "maximum of two numbers (prod)"() {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        a  | b  || c
        2  | 4  || 4
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach requires a lot of duplication: you have to duplicate test methods and you can't re-use the same name (compiler does not allow to do that). It's pretty error-prone - you have to pay attention to put the same test body to all methods that should test the same stuff, but with different data. Another thing is that condition passed to `@IgnoreIf` will have to be modified if you introduce 3rd environment - in this case you will specify it something like that:

```java
@IgnoreIf({ !(System.getProperty('execution.environment') in ['staging', 'prod']) })
```

I guess you see how much problematic it starts to be.

Answer (score 0):

Spock has [Multi-Variable Data Pipes](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html) to handle this. You can move the "logic" to a data-driven method.

```java
class MathSpec extends Specification {

   def "maximum of two numbers"(int a, int b, int c) {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        [a, b, c] << getData()
    }

    def getData() {
        if (System.getProperty("Staging"))
            [ [1, 3, 3] ]
       else
            [ [3, 5, 5] ]
   }
}
```

In your case, I would use an abstract `getData()` method.
I would implement in `getData()` in two different classes `MathProductionSpec` and `MathStagingSpec`
I would use [spock annotations](https://github.com/roygrssmn/spock-annotations) to execute according to your environment.

example:

```java
abstract class MathSpec extends Specification {

    def "maximum of two numbers"(int a, int b, int c) {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        [a, b, c] << getData()
    }

    def abstract getData()
}
```

```java
@Production
class MathProductionSpec extends MathSpec {
    def getData() {
        [ [4, 2, 4] ]
    }
}
```

```java
@Staging
class MathStagingSpec extends MathSpec {
    def getData() {
        [ [1, 3, 3] ]
    }
}
```